# Can the Superposition of Two Light Waves Make a Wave with a "New" Frequency?

Tags: waves

I'm borderline illiterate when it comes to physics, so my apologies if my question and additional explanation make no sense.

The sort of case I am thinking is this: If light wave A, which has a frequency of 450 THz, is superimposed on light wave B, which has a frequency of 100 THz, will the wave that results from their interference (can we call this a third wave, wave C?) have a different frequency than A or B?

If so, what will its (wave C's) frequency be, and what equation gives that result?

Thanks

Comment: Some search terms: "beat frequency," "nonlinear optics," "frequency-doubling."

Comment: Your question is not well defined, because superposition is not the same as interference. Independent light waves don't interfere, even of the same frequency. Despite naive views motivated by classical physics, the quantum nature of light cannot be ignored. The only light interference that exists is of a wave with itself.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the way physicists define things is that the only kind of wave with a well-defined frequency is a sine wave. So by that definition, the superposition will not have any well-defined frequency. We'd define it as a mixture.

An alternative definition is that you can say a periodic (i.e., repeating) wave has a frequency, which is the inverse of its period. This definition is particularly appropriate when dealing with sound and music, because it corresponds closely to how the ear-brain system perceives pitch. By that definition (which is not really appropriate or useful for light waves), your wave would have a frequency, because the two frequencies being combined are related by a rational-number ratio. Both frequencies in your example are multiples of 50 THz, so the period of the combined wave corresponds to that frequency.

If you superpose the waves and then apply some nonlinear processing, you can get other frequencies, such as the difference ("beat") frequency. Some forms of radio use this type of technique.

Answer (score 0):

> If light wave A, which has a frequency of 450 THz, is superimposed on
>   light wave B, which has a frequency of 100 THz, will the wave that
>   results from their interference (can we call this a third wave, wave
>   C?)

No, that last part is not possible at the quantum level. There is no sort of "composite wave" that is created when light interferes.

Light does not "mix" in the fashion you outline. If you shine two beams of light at each other, they go right past each other. There's no point where you have this "third wave" as you would in a water wave or something like that.

Now you have no doubt seen light interfering, so what's going on? What you're seeing in a *probability distribution*, that the light preferentially goes in certain directions (sort of) and not others, resulting in light and dark areas. It LOOKS like what happens with water waves, but the underlying physics is totally different.

If you think of the quanta as particles with some sort of quality that fools you into thinking they're a wave, then this outcome becomes obvious, the particles are just going here and there and they're too small to bump into each other. Of course, you can also think of it as a wave that fools you into thinking it's a particle. Both are equally false.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. The question is classical, so the quantum stuff isn't relevant. It's not true that you can't mix two optical plane waves. This is a standard thing done in optics, e.g., with a half-silvered mirror.